# Compiling module using SDK throws warning message: libelf-dev not found

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto

We have customized intel core-i7-64 machine and we developed Yocto image and SDK for the hardware.

After sourcing the environment script and running `make modules_prepare`, I get the following warning:

```
Makefile:956: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
```

The same error happens when I compile out of tree modules. How can I remove this error? What all packages should we need to add to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `libelf-dev` and `elfutils` package. If you are using Ubuntu or any Debian variant then use the following command to install them.

```
sudo apt install libelf-dev
```

Comment: Should we not include this package in the SDK or final image

Comment: I think you should as it is the compilation dependency. It also appears when you compile the upstream kernel standalone.

Comment: Say, I have SDK for ARM and my development machine in Intel. When i run apt-get it will have libraries of Intel and not ARM. Is this correct

Comment: Well the toolchains will be different in both cases and each toolchain will look into its own set of libraries. If a specific library is not present in compiled form for a specific arch then you will have to compile it for that specific arch

Comment: Looking at the Makefile, it is using HOSTCC to check for the library present or not and not CC. Why is this package not included in the dependency list of Yocto for Ubuntu

Comment: Seeing this I assume that the developer himself need to take care of installation of the build system dependencies not the yocto system. https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=yNi6BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=yocto+libelf+dependency&source=bl&ots=HYf75kOpCa&sig=ACfU3U3SeF9I09e_soXRO-66qZSoEif1PA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDiNP8_t3gAhVRsqQKHRDfC10Q6AEwBnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=yocto%20libelf%20dependency&f=false

Comment: @Rajnesh - I face a situation which I already have the `libelf-dev` package, YET I still face this warning. What could be the reason? WHat there is more to check?